# Autocomplete google maps with JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete, maps

is there any good example for Google Maps Autocomplete with JSF for searching for city?
Maybe with primefaces?

Is there a option to get this city via JSON and than the result to the primefaces autocomplete?
Thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is use `Google API`: [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete?csw=1)

There are some examples you can search via internet